# Dynamically creating parameters in nested rust macros

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I've been tinkering around with Rust's macro system for a while now, and recently got interested in nesting two macros together, like this:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    () => {
        macro_rules! bar {
            () => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Relating to the example, I wanted to dynamically make parameter names in `bar!` which were passed into `foo!`, to obtain a result like this:

```rust
foo!(bar, baz); 

// The above call creates a macro, bar!, with the following definition:
macro_rules! bar {
    ( $bar:literal, $baz:literal ) => {
        println!("{}", stringify!( $bar, $baz ));
    }
}
```

To give a better idea of what I'm trying to do, here was my initial thought process on how this would work (this should parse exactly to the definition shown above):

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ( $( $attr:ident ), * ) => {
        macro_rules! bar {
            // the designator $$attr:literal consists of two parts - $attr,
            // which should be replaced with the arguments passed into foo!,
            // and $__:literal, which creates a literal designator for each of
            // the arguments from foo! for bar!
            ( $( $$attr:literal ), * ) => {
                // $( $$attr ), * follows the same logic as above
                println!("{}", stringify!( $( $$attr ), * ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does look very weird, and sure enough, it didn't work, giving an error mentioning [meta-variable expressions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3086) and [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/83527), both of which looked unrelated (full error can be seen on [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&code=macro_rules!%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(%20%24(%20%24attr%3Aident%20)%2C%20*%20)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20macro_rules!%20bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20designator%20%24%24attr%3Aliteral%20consists%20of%20two%20parts%20-%20%24attr%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20which%20should%20be%20replaced%20with%20the%20arguments%20passed%20into%20foo!%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20and%20%24__%3Aliteral%2C%20which%20creates%20a%20literal%20designator%20for%20each%20of%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20the%20arguments%20from%20foo!%20for%20bar!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%20%24(%20%24%24attr%3Aliteral%20)%2C%20*%20)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%24(%20%24%24attr%20)%2C%20*%20follows%20the%20same%20logic%20as%20above%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20stringify!(%20%24(%20%24%24attr%20)%2C%20*%20))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)).

Does anyone know if it is possible to dynamically create a macro with variables like this, and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, however...

You cannot insert the `$` sign, as it is reserved for metavariables.

You have two options to tackle that.

On stable, you need to pass `$` to the macro. Then it can refer to it using the metavariable.

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ( $dollar:tt $( $attr:ident ), * ) => {
        macro_rules! bar {
            ( $( $dollar $attr:literal ), * ) => {
                println!("{}", stringify!( $( $dollar $attr ), * ));
            }
        }
    }
}

foo!($ bar, baz);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=916e7cee0e087bfcfdb7ccd9db3021c9).

On nightly, you can escape the dollar sign: this is part of the feature [`macro_metavar_expr`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3086-macro-metavar-expr.html) the compiler mentioned. You do it using `$$`:

```rust
#![feature(macro_metavar_expr)]

macro_rules! foo {
    ( $( $attr:ident ), * ) => {
        macro_rules! bar {
            ( $( $$ $attr:literal ), * ) => {
                println!("{}", stringify!( $( $$ $attr ), * ));
            }
        }
    }
}

foo!(bar, baz);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5ca36aebe6320e21811344db54b47c33).

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought this feature was a bit too over-the-top to be possible, but Rust never disappoints :) After some more digging, it looks like the nightly feature is [(very!) active in development](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/95860) and is coming as soon as 1.62.0! Also, you might want to change your link for `macro_metavar_expr` to [this](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3086-macro-metavar-expr.html) - it seems to have the proper information.

Comment: @AyushGarg Oh yeah, I sometimes link to the unstable book or to the RFCs book or to the RFC document, but I didn't see the RFC document hasn't been updated to include the  tracking issue & RFC PR this time :(